# Mix-blend-mode breaks when out of viewport

Tags: css, sass, gsap

I'm having a slight problem with mix-blend-mode.

The text on top is set on mix-blend-mode:difference. When you scroll the text out of view and the scroll back up the blend mode breaks, and goes back to usual if you scroll a little bit more.

It's worth mentioning that the website is being smooth-scrolled using transform3d.

Live example here:
http://hooliganspro.co.il/omri/segoli/ (desktop version only)

this is how it should be:
[image]

this is how it looks when it breaks after scrolling:
[image]

Comment: I found out on CanIUse that there is a known issue to this attribute on Chrome/Opera. https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode

Comment: It works perfectly fine in Chrome version 67.0.3396.87. (nice effect!)

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on Google Chrome Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @SirExotic thanks! have you tried scrolling all the way to the bottom and then back to the top?

Comment: @user3160630 Yes, no problems whatsoever.